# Are there infinite combinations of Euler angles to describe the same rotation?

Tags: geometry, rotations

In XYZ convention, the Euler angles (0, 180, 0) describe the same rotation as (180, 0, -180).

- Are there always multiple ways to describe the same rotation with Euler angles?
- Is there even an infinite number of ways?
- If so, how can this be proved?

EDIT: Of course, I do not mean the 360° periodicity of angles!

Comment: See for example a problem of so-called gimbal lock https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock#Gimbal_lock_in_three_dimensions where for second rotation by π/2 we have really infinite number of ways of assigning first and third angle. For other cases I think there is no infinite number, see for example  extracting Euler angles
https://www.google.pl/search?q=calculating+euler+angles+from+rotation+matrix&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=_kK5WJf-Bazi8AfO_J_ADw#q=euler+angles+from+rotation+matrix+pdf&start=0&*

Comment: You mean ignoring multiples of 360° for the angles?

Comment: In generally no. What you have described above is a degenerate case.

Comment: @ja72: Yes, ignoring multiples of 360°!